# C# - Comparing items between 2 lists

Tags: c#, algorithm

I've got two lists with the following identical fields (but different content):

- TriangleID
- Perimeter(in pixels)

My task is to extract the *couples* of triangles that have their perimeter *difference smaller* than a *fixed threshold*.

I'd like to do it with **Linq**.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with sample inputs and expected results based on those sample inputs.

Comment: "I'd like to do it with Linq" And why do you want this? Do you already try something that didn´t work which makes you feel Linq will do what you want?

Comment: The volumes are quite big.  [editing, I commited before ending the message]

Comment: That makes absolulety no difference when using Linq. I guess without you providing anything about your current approaches and where you are stuck no-one here is willing to do your job.

Comment: The volumes are quite big (some millions items in each list).
What I'm doing is the astrometric resolution of an image.

I've got stars in my image and stars from a catalog.
Each of the stars is characterized by coordinates (x, y).
I've found out all the possible triangles with the stars from my image and stars from the catalogue (C(Nstarintheimage; 3) and C(Nstarinthecatalogue; 3)).

Now I've to find the matches between them: find the triangles built with the stars from the image that have a perimeter similar to the triangles built with the stars from the catalogue

Comment: Sort the collection by `Perimeter`. For each triangle in the collection, find bounds `perimeter - threshold` and `perimeter + threshold` with a help of *binary search*; enumerate triangles within bounds and return pairs

Comment: Not properly here for someone doing my job. I've tested some Linq statements I've found after some multiple searches over SO some hours ago but without any success. I'm trying to find them out again and post here. I probably wrote it wrong, it could be that Linq is not the best solution considering the high volumes

Comment: This is what I tested before but it didn't seem to return what I was expecting (I tested it on a small subset and it was returning 0 lines in result):

var result = (from t1 in TriangleList1
              where TriangleList2.Any(t2 => (t1.Perimeter - t2.Perimeter) < 10
              select t1);

Comment: Please add any relevant information directly into the question, as it´s hard to read them from the comments. This includes what you´ve tried already and where *exactly* you´re stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not *Linq*, but collection's **size** (`N`) that matters. In the *worst case* (all equal triangles) you have to return all possible pairs of triangles as a solution; we have

```
 N * N
```

pairs. If you have `N ~ 1e6` triangles you are going to obtain as many as *trillion* (`1e12`) pairs as an answer. It's too much for the modern personal computers (in case of supercomputer, however, you can try solving the problem).

Let's assume that you don't have the *worst case* and you expect to obtain at most `~ N` pairs. You can do it like this (C# pseudocode):

```
// Sort triangles by their perimeters
firstList.Sort((t1, t2) => t1.Perimeter.CompareTo(t2.Perimeter));

foreach (left in secondList) {
  //TODO: you have to implement BinarySearchIndex
  int from = firstList.BinarySearchIndex(left.Period - threshould);
  int to = firstList.BinarySearchIndex(left.Period + threshould);

  // Scan all triangles within borders
  for (int i = leftBorder; i <= rightBorder; ++i) {
    triangle right = firstList[i];

    // return pair if right and left are different triangles
    if (right.Id != left.Id)
      yield return Pair(left, right);
  } 
}
```

Time complexity is

```
O(N * log(N))  +  /* sorting */ + 
O(N * log(N))     /* foreach (N) * 
                     Binary search (log N) * 
                     for (1 - not the worst case) */ =
O(N * log(N))
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, I'm going to try this approach right now

Comment: Thanks a lot Dmitry. It worked. I've been able to compare 2 ~1Mi lines lists in few seconds

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming it's ok to return a Triangle and associate a collection of nearby other Triangles, instead of returning a list of pairs.

The idea is to sort both lists and then iterate through them. The first list will iterate over every single item, and compare the perimeter to items in the second list. But not every item in the second list needs to be checked. Since both lists are sorted, you can iterate through the second list until you no longer find perimeters within a cutoff. The other time saving method is advancing the starting index of the second list based on the difference to the perimeter in the first list; this is left as an exercise for the reader.

```cs
public class Triangle
{
    public int TriangleId {get; set;}
    public int Perimeter {get; set;}
}

// Returns a dictionary, that each triangle has an associated list of other triangles
// with a perimeter within a specified distance. This list may be empty.
public Dictionary<Triangle, List<Triangle>> NearbyPerimeter(List<Triangle> primary, List<Triangle> compareList, int maxDistance)
{
    // sort ~ O(n log n)
    // The sort is required to make an orderly advance through both lists, otherwise
    // every element needs to be compared to every other element.
    var sorteda = primary.OrderBy(x => x.Perimeter);

    // Call ToList to allow indexing with []
    var sortedb = compareList.OrderBy(x => x.Perimeter).ToList();

    var results = new Dictionary<Triangle, List<Triangle>>();

    int minCompareIndex = 0;
    int compareCount = compareList.Count;

    // ~ O(n)
    foreach (var tprime in sorteda)
    {
        var neighbors = new List<Triangle>();

        // Add logic to advance minCompareIndex based on 
        // which is larger, tprime.Perimeter or sortedb[minCompareIndex].Perimeter

        int i =  minCompareIndex;
        var foundMatch = false;

        // Until the missing logic above is added, this is O(n) x O(n) so ~ O(n^2)
        while (i < compareCount)
        {
            var second = sortedb[i];
            if (Math.Abs(tprime.Perimeter - second.Perimeter) < maxDistance)
            {
                neighbors.Add(second);

                foundMatch = true;
            }
            else if (foundMatch)
            {
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }

        results.Add(tprime, neighbors);
    }

    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `Linq` but with a small artefact - basically what you need is a Cartesian product of both collections and a filter on the differences. The Cartesian product can be obtained using `Join` and an always `true` condition.

The code below should do the trick (I'm assuming the lists contain a class called `Triangle`; if this is not the case adjust the code to your needs):

```
var results = list1.Join(list2,
        _ => true,
        _ => true,
        (t1, t2) => new { Triangle1 = t1, Triangle2 = t2})
    .Where(pair = > Math.Abs(pair.Triangle1.Perimeter - pair.Triangle2.Perimeter) < threshold)
    .Select(pair => new{/*…*/});
```

Comment: The cartesian product of two lists with "some millions of items" is going to be quite large.

Comment: @RePierre: "The volumes are quite big (some millions items in each list)" (see comments to the question) and so we have `N * N = 1e12` items to work with...

Comment: I did not see those comments; thanks for pointing it out. I will however leave the answer as an alternative for when the collections size is indeed quite small.